# Spyder not throwing the type error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I was working in Spyder on python 3 and trying to get some input from the user so i accidentally wrote

```
g = input(print("Give the letter: "))
```

while it should be

```
g = str(input("Give the letter: "))
```

But Spyder IPython console ran it and didn't said its a TypeError
but when I ran the code on an online python console it said that its a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'.

I know that its an error as print() returns None, so the input() is having both NoneType and str.

So my question is why Spyder IPython console didn't mentioned this error?

[image]

Comment: I am like a dilettante here so please correct me if I am wrong here or if I don't have the full info on this

Comment: Can't replicate this problem in either Python 3 or 2. Have you posted the actual code? Where is the `+` coming from? Please post the full traceback. What is the online Python console that produced this error?

Comment: Hi @mhawke I was getting the error on edx console while I was submitting my code. But I am also unable to replicate it on pythontutor

Comment: Is that an error or not? I think it is since print() returns None so g will have NoneType and string both

Comment: The string would be printed to the console, by `print()`, not by `input()`. The return value of `print()` is `None` which is then converted to the string `'None`' and that is the prompt used. There should not be any error at all.

Comment: BTW it's not necessary to convert the return value of `input()` into a string - it already is.

Comment: @mhawke ok got it so I don't need to put str before input incase the user's input is string but I need to put int if the input is an integer. And can you please look in the screenshot I uploaded that why None is not printed out ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
g = str(raw_input("Give the letter: "))
```

Comment: OP already said they are using Python 3. `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3

Comment: Hi Arsh, my later sentence str(input(" ")) is working fine. I just needed to know why spyder's python console is not showing error for the first line of code. you can see the image I have uploaded